# Fermi energy lying in the forbidden gap

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, fermi-energy

So, according to the my textbook(Fundamentals of physics by Halliday & Resnick), the Fermi level is the highest occupied level at absolute temperature ($T=0 K$) and the energy corresponding to it is called the Fermi energy $E_F$. Now my question is how for semiconductors the Fermi level lies in the middle of band gab. I have read most of the answers for similar questions that were posted here before, and now I know that this definition of the fermi level is over-simplified. But I'm still having a hard time understanding how could it be in the band gab where there is supposed to be no occupied levels at all.

Comment: So, that definition is just fine for metals, where the Fermi energy lies in a partially filled band. Kind of. Because there are plenty of metals where the bands are not free-electron like and the Fermi energy is not always in a partially filled band. But, the Fermi energy is where the Fermi function (which is independent from any band structure) equals 1/2. That is all. Whether there are states to occupy there or not is irrelevant.

Comment: I got it thanks!